# javafx set onkeypressed for an editable comboboxtablecell

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have an editable tableview with editable column with this cell factory

```
tblColumn.setCellFactory(t -> { 
                        ComboBoxTableCell myComboBoxTableCell = new ComboBoxTableCell();
                        myComboBoxTableCell.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
                            System.out.println("key pressed");
                            KeyCode code = e.getCode();
                            System.out.println("code "+code);
                        });
                         myComboBoxTableCell.setComboBoxEditable(true);
                        return myComboBoxTableCell;
                    });
```

what i'm trying to do is to get letter typed in the editable `comboBoxTableCell`, but when i type, the `onKeyPressed` method is not fired. am i doing something wrong?
PLease help.

Comment: If you replace `setOnKeyPressed` with `setOnKeyTyped`, are there any different results?

Comment: Thank you for your answer
No it's same no events fired
i  changed the Cell from ComboBoxTableCell to TextFieldTableCell and on edit mode the onKeypressed still not firing.
I don't know what the problem is.